# Avoiding BadURIExceptions while reading Turtle file

Tags: java, rdf, jena

I want to parse a Turtle file using this simple code:

```
public void read(String path) throws IOException {
    File sourceFile = new File(path);

    Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
    InputStream in = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);

    model.read(in, "", "TTL");
    model.write(System.out);
}
```

Sometimes it complains about some URIs:

> Exception in thread "main" com.hp.hpl.jena.shared.BadURIException: Only well-formed absolute URIrefs can be included in RDF/XML output: `<http://thetvdb.com/?tab=episode&seriesid={/tv/tv_series_episode/season.series[/authority/thetvdb/series]}&seasonid={/tv/tv_series_episode/season[/authority/thetvdb/season]}&id=337070>` Code: 0/ILLEGAL_CHARACTER in QUERY: The character violates the grammar rules for URIs/IRIs.

How can I avoid this?  Obviously some URIs are violating the grammar rules for URIs so 
do I need to preprocess my input data, or is there an option to  configure this using Jena?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Updated Answer

As Joshua Taylor has pointed out (and once his formatting has made the query a bit more readable) the problem is that the URIs in your data are just plain broken.  One of the restrictions of RDF/XML is that only well formed URIs can be output and as the error shows in your case they are not.

Either you need to pre-process the input or you need to get the data producer to fix their data.  Jena doesn't have any support built in for fixing up broken data like this.

### Original Answer - Making relative URIs absolute

The URIs in your data aren't breaking any grammar rules rather they are expressed as relative URIs and you have not provided a base URI to resolve these against so Jena leaves them as is when reading them (though it will issue warnings about this).

However when you come to writing out the data (in RDF/XML because you didn't specify a specific format to output) Jena needs to make the URIs absolute.  Again since you haven't specified a base URI it cannot do this and on writing this causes an error.

You can work around this by making the URIs absolute either when you parse them in or when you write them out.

To make them absolute when parsed in specify a base URI to your `read()` operation e.g.

```
model.read(in, "http://example.org/", "TTL");
```

To make them absolute when writing them out specify a base URI to your `write()` operation e.g.

```
model.write(System.out, "RDF/XML", "http://example.org/");
```

You don't necessarily need to do both, doing it on writing is more flexible since it allows you to write out the data using different base URIs which results in producing different output data.  However if you do it on reading then you prevent other code from changing the data by writing it with a different base URI later.

**NB** For whatever reason the language and base URI arguments are in different orders between the `read()` and `write()` calls.

Comment: The URI in the error message _looks_ absolute though: `<http://thetvdb.com/?tab=episode&seriesid={/tv/tv_series_episode/season.series[/authority/thetvdb/series]}&seasonid={/tv/tv_series_episode/season[/authority/thetvdb/season]}&id=337070>`  Is it just misleading and it's actually relative?  Even so, if that's the case, why does message say "Code: 0/ILLEGAL_CHARACTER in QUERY: The character violates the grammar rules for URIs/IRIs."  That doesn't sound like an issue with absolute vs. relative IRIs.

Comment: (I'm not saying the answer is necessarily wrong;  but if the error message is to be trusted, I'm missing the connection between it and relative vs. absolute IRIs.)

Comment: Good point, was hard to read the question before you reformatted it.  Updated my answer to reflect this

Comment: Yeah, it wasn't very easy to read.  I'm more surprised that the OP _accepted_ the answer though;  I don't see how the original solutions would have fixed the OP's problem. The updated answer make sense, though.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Well unless Jena is treating the URI as relative when you supply a Base and somehow forming a valid URI that way??

Comment: I'd wondered if maybe something in that weird IRI made it get treated that way, but if that's the case, then sometime really strange must be happening.  (Or else it's one of those weird cases in the URI/IRI specs.)